# input value in jquery fancybox

Tags: jquery, input, fancybox

Like asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1482873/input-inside-fancybox) I got the problem, that I cannot read the value of an input type="text" field after writing something into it.

The event is fired correctly, and with other inputs outside the fancybox it works great.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1482873/input-inside-fancybox/1543514#1543514) please. I Hope it will help.